# Calling MATLAB Function in python with 2d array as parameter

Tags: python, matlab, wrapper

I have a python script in which i want to call a matlab function with passing a 2d list and want to return and use the processed matlab output in python again.

i am now using this library

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
```

Comment: Was there anything particularly unclear in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) of this subject?

Comment: We are already connected but our problem is that how we can get a 2d array in matlab function?

Comment: Was there anything particularly unclear in the [specific documentation for the actual thing you are trying to do](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-matlab-arrays-in-python.html)?